# Sphinx - Searching For Empty Term

Tags: sphinx

In the past I was using the following to find all the newest video in my database,
however after moving to my new server it no longer seems to work. I've tried to play
around with the settings in sphinx.conf but to no avail. I need to search for empty terms to find various things such as the newest videos, the total video count etc. Hope someone can help!

```
$client = new SphinxClient();
        // Set search options
        $client->SetServer('localhost', 9312);
        $client->SetConnectTimeout(1);
        $client->SetArrayResult(true);
        $client->SetLimits($offset, $VIDEOS_PER_PAGE, $offset+$VIDEOS_PER_PAGE);
        $client->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC,"date");
        // Query the index
        $results = $client->query('',"test1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if enable_star is set to 1 in your config

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-enable-star.html

Comment: What has enable_star got to do with the question?

Comment: the user wantmake empty search no ? He say, it's was working before, change server. Perhaps config file has change. no ?

Comment: What has enable_star to do with empty search? Yes something has changed granted, but dont see the connection with enable_star - which is for controlling prefix/infix searches.

Comment: ok so 

When I start to accept empty search (it was with 0.9.8) The only setting I had change  was set enable_star to 1. 

But probably other option was already set in right value.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231262/perform-an-empty-query-with-filters-in-sphinx

Comment: That is what is technically known as a red-herring. enable_star really has nothing to do with. (searching with a single '*' only **appears** to work, because the star is NOT in charset_table, and so gets removed - leaving an EMPTY query.

Comment: OK, so I remove my answer or I let to preserve discussion ?